# cannot verify api.nuget.org's certificate, issued by ‘CN=Microsoft Azure TLS Issuing CA 01,O=Microsoft Corporation,C=US’

Tags: c#, azure, ssl, .net-core, nuget

On **Ubuntu** `20.04` I have installed `dotnet` SDK.

SDK version: `5.0.300`

When I want to add a package, I get this error:

```
info : Adding PackageReference for package 'System.Text.Json' into project '/temp/net/net.csproj'.
error: Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
error:   The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
error:   The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: UntrustedRoot
```

And when I try to get `index.json` in terminal using `wget https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json`, I get this error:

```
Resolving api.nuget.org (api.nuget.org)... 152.199.23.209
Connecting to api.nuget.org (api.nuget.org)|152.199.23.209|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify api.nuget.org's certificate, issued by ‘CN=Microsoft Azure TLS Issuing CA 01,O=Microsoft Corporation,C=US’:
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to api.nuget.org insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
```

What should I do?

Comment: Is your OS up-to-date otherwise? I had a similar issue, and explicitly reinstalling the certificate package helped. But I don't remember which package that was. Maybe `ca-cacert` or `ca-certificates`.

Comment: I guess my OS is up to date, because it's configured to get the latest updates automatically. I searched to see what certificates should I download and install manually, but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Try `sudo apt remove ca-cacert` and `sudo apt install ca-cacert` (ignore the dependency warnings). Repeat with `ca-certificates`, if needed.

Comment: I did it for both `ca-cacert` and `ca-certificates`, but I still get the error.

Comment: Then I don't know how to get the certificate chain fixed, I'm sorry. Maybe you get better answers at superuser.

Comment: It's OK. Thank you.